# Why would a switched neutral situation only act up after years of use?

Tags: electrical, switch

My front porch light fixture (it has a dusk sensor, fwiw) suddenly stopped working. After checking the voltages and finding I was getting 110 volts when the switch was in the on position and 84 volts when the switch was off, I assumed there was a switched neutral. After tracing it through, I found the problem at the switch. Everything is ok now.

As a novice, I am now wondering about the underlying theory behind all this.

1) Why would this fixture work fine for years and then suddenly decide that it's had enough?

2) If the voltage coming through was 110 when the switch was in the on position, why wouldn't the light turn on?

Comment: What exactly were you measuring?

Comment: The voltages in the socket.

Comment: The 84 volts you found with the switch off is what's known as floating voltage.  The concept your missing is that you were measuring voltage and not current.  Situations like these are some of the many reasons switched neutrals are no longer used.

Comment: @Tyson gotcha. That would presumably explain #2. What about #1?

Comment: You'd have to tell us what "I found the problem at the switch" means.  What did you correct?  A loose connection? If so the loose connection could provide continuity but not carry a load (current).

Comment: @Tyson I had the hot and neutral lines coming in reversed from the breaker. This while the line going from the switch to the fixture was still wired as what should have been correct. So the hot from breaker was connected to "neutral" of fixture (which was showing continuity to ground only when the switch was in the on position), while neutral from the breaker was switching on and off to the "hot" going to the fixture. Thanks for your time btw.

Comment: Unless someone beats me to it I'll reply again later when I have scrap paper/pen... Read last comment twice and couldn't follow it in my head.

Comment: I should have read it a third time.. It made sense this time.  In the process of making that fix, I suspect you also corrected a loose connection which would have been getting hot over time when the light was on, but not hot enough to be a problem generally, over time tho that heat cool cycle develops higher resistance in the connection.  Voltage can still pass the bad connection, but it can no longer carry current.

Comment: @Tyson Third time's a charm;) Interesting suggestion. Thank you again for your time and trouble.